# How to set position of UILabel relative to Image in a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I've created a custom cell, `MatchCenterCell`, in which I create a `UILabel` called `priceLabel`, which sits inside of a cell in a `UITableView`. The way it's currently setup is like so:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.PriceLabel  = [[ UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 35, 70, 40)];
    }
    return self;
}
```

However, this causes issues because the image size of each cell varies, so having an x coordinate of 90 means that sometimes it will be misaligned, like the "Best Match" label shows below: 
[image]

How can I make the x coordinate relative to the `cell.imageView` so that it lines up the way `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` do above it?

Comment: What @rdelmar said. You can add constraints directly to the label to ensure it sits vertically and horizontally centered in relation to the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [auto-layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) as suggested in the comments, or override layout subviews as follows:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews()
{
    [super layoutSubViews];
    self.detailTextLabel.y = 0;
    self.detailTextLabel.x = self.imageView.right + 10; 
    self.detailTextLabel.height = self.contentView.height;
    self.detailTextLabel.width = self.contentView.width - self.detailTextLabel.x;
}
```

The above uses [CKUITools](https://github.com/genericspecific/CKUITools) which adds some convenience methods when doing custom layouts.

Comment: My `UITableView` was initialized programmatically though, not through storyboard. How would I use autolayout in that case? Where would I put the code you posted?

Comment: You can still use auto-layout programmatically, but the above example is *not*auto-layout just overrides layoutSubviews in your custom cell. .